# Sql, Asp.net - using left join data being multiple

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

My data keeps getting multiple in display even i only have one reference number in my main table which in TicketTb, can you help me how to solve this.

//TicketTb Table
[image: This is TicketTb]

//TicketNotification Table
[image: This is TicketNotification]

//TicketForwardTb Table

[image: This is TicketForwardTb]

//TicketUser Table
[image: This is TicketUser]

//TicketFwdNotification Table

[image: This is TicketFwdNotification]

This is my Controller in ASP.NET MVC, this is way of retrieving my data from my Stored Procedure.

```
public JsonResult GetTicket(string Username, string Usertype, string is_category)
{
    Username = Session["uname"].ToString();
    Usertype = Session["UserType"].ToString();    
    return Json(ticketDataAccessLayer.GetAllTicket(Username, Usertype, is_category), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

readonly string connectionString = ConnectionString.CName;

public List<Ticket> GetAllTicket(string Username, string Usertype, string is_category)
{
    List<Ticket> lstTicket = new List<Ticket>();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spFetchAllTicket", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", Username);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usertype", Usertype);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@is_category", is_category);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
            ticket.Tid = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Tid"]);
            ticket.Details = rdr["Details"].ToString();
            ticket.ErrorType = rdr["ErrorType"].ToString();
            ticket.DateOccurence = rdr["DateOccurence"].ToString();
            ticket.DateCreate = rdr["DateCreate"].ToString();
            ticket.TicketStatus = rdr["TicketStatus"].ToString();
            ticket.TicketSubject = rdr["TicketSubject"].ToString();
            ticket.TicketNumber = rdr["TicketNumber"].ToString();
            ticket.NotifStatus = rdr["NotifStatus"].ToString();
            ticket.FStatus = rdr["FStatus"].ToString();
            ticket.UserTicket = rdr["CreatedUser"].ToString();
            ticket.FwdStatus = rdr["FwdStatus"].ToString();
            ticket.ForwardTo = rdr["ForwardTo"].ToString();
            ticket.TimeRun = rdr["TimeRun"].ToString();
            ticket.TimeResponse = rdr["TimeResponse"].ToString();
            ticket.RunTimeClose = rdr["RunTimeClose"].ToString();
            lstTicket.Add(ticket);
        }
        con.Close();
```

This is my view .cshtml where i display my data which getting repeated even i only have one data in my main table.

```
<table id="ticketTable" class="display table table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Ticket Number</th>
            <th>Created By</th>
            <th>Date & Time Created</th>
            <th>Date & Time Occured</th>
            <th>Error Type</th>
            <th>Details</th>
            <th>Forward To</th>
            <th>Running Time</th>
            <th>Response Time</th>
            <th>
                <select name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">All</option>
                    <option value="Open">Open</option>
                    <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
                </select>
            </th>
            <th>Total Run</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
            var dataTable = $('#ticketTable').DataTable({
                "language": {
            "emptyTable": "No Transaction"
                },
            ajax: {
        url: "/Ticket/GetTicket/" + is_category,
                dataType: "json",
                retrieve: "true",
                processing: "true",
                serverSide: "true",

                type: "POST",
                dataSrc: "",
                data: { is_category: is_category },

            },
            columnDefs: [
                {
        targets: [9],
                    orderable: false,
                },
            ],

            columns: [
                {
        data: "TicketNumber",

                    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                var ticketNumber = row.TicketNumber
                        var NotifStatus = row.NotifStatus
                        var Fwd = '<span class="badge badge-danger">' + row.FStatus + '</span>'

                        if ("@ViewBag.Usertype" === 'Admin') {

                    if (NotifStatus == 0) {
                        return '<span class="badge badge-danger">New</span> ' + ticketNumber + ' ';
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        return ticketNumber;
                    }



                }




                else if ("@ViewBag.Usertype" === 'User')
                {

                    return Fwd + " " + ticketNumber;
                }

            },
                },

                {

        data: "UserTicket"
                },

                {
        data: "DateCreated",
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                var DateTime = row.DateCreate;
                return DateTime;
            },
                },
                {
        data: "DateOccurence",
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                var DateTime = row.DateOccurence;
                return DateTime;
            },
                },
                {
        data: "ErrorType"
                },
                {
        data: "TicketNumber",
                    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info viewdetails" id="' + data + '">View</button>';
            },
                },



                {
        data: "ForwardTo"
                },

                {
        data: "TimeRun"
                },

                {
        data: "TimeResponse"
                },

                {
        data: "TicketStatus"
                },
                {
        data: "RunTimeClose"
                },
            ]

        });

//SQL CODE
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spFetchAllTicket]  

(
@Usertype nvarchar(50)
)
as        
Begin    
IF @Usertype='Admin'
begin
         select TicketTb.* ,  TicketNotification.* ,  TicketForwardTb.* , TicketUser.* , TicketFwdNotification.*
             from TicketTb

             LEFT JOIN TicketNotification on TicketTb.TicketNumber = TicketNotification.NotifTicketID
             LEFT JOIN TicketForwardTb on TicketTb.TicketNumber = TicketForwardTb.FTicketNumber
             LEFT JOIN TicketUser on TicketTb.UserTicket = TicketUser.UserName
             LEFT JOIN TicketFwdNotification on TicketTb.TicketNumber = TicketFwdNotification.FwdTicketNumber
            order by TicketTb.Tid   
end
```

Comment: what is the output you are getting from above query and what is the output you are expecting.

Comment: Both `TicketForwardTb` and `TicketFwdNotification` have 2 records with the same TicketNumber. You therefore get 4 results for that ticket .

Comment: @DarkRob, here's my update

Comment: @codeSeven: as in previous comment Robert has said, you have multiple entries for reference of one `Ticketnumber`, therefore you are getting multiple result.